# How to set the width of a JTable columns

Tags: java, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I read all the posted messages concerned with setting the column width of a JTable.
I literally copied the posted answers just changing the JTable name but kept getting error messages for each statement that tries to set the current column width.

I simply define a JTable with 7 fixed columns whose names are passed to the DefaultTableModel.
I must be missing something but... what?

I am posting just the few relevant lines.
Thank you in advance for any suggestion.

```
       import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
       import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;


    JString[] columnNames = {"New Line Name", "Point1", "Point2", "Angle", "Parallel Line Name",      
                                 "Distance From Line", "Group"};
        DefaultTableModel linesTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null,columnNames);
        JTable tblLines = new JTable(linesTableModel);
    TableColumnModel colModel = tblLines.getColumnModel(); 
    colModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
    colModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
    colModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
    colModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);
    colModel.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(200);
    colModel.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(100);
    colModel.getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(90);
```

Comment: (1-) *but kept getting error messages for each statement that tries to set the current column width.* - and the error message is??? Most an [mre] demonstrating the problem.  Of course the code you posted won't compile since you can't have code after import statements. We can't guess what your real code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

I went to the trouble of creating the rest of the code.  Here's the GUI.

[image: Example]

Other than the columns not wide enough for the column headers, I don't see a problem.

Here's the complete runnable code, which is what you should be including with your question.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumnModel;

public class JTableExample implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new JTableExample());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JTable Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(createTablePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createTablePanel() {
        String[] columnNames = { "New Line Name", "Point1", "Point2", "Angle",
                "Parallel Line Name", "Distance From Line", "Group" };
        DefaultTableModel linesTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(null,
                columnNames);
        JTable tblLines = new JTable(linesTableModel);
        TableColumnModel colModel = tblLines.getColumnModel();
        colModel.getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
        colModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(50);
        colModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(80);
        colModel.getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(150);
        colModel.getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(200);
        colModel.getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(100);
        colModel.getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(90);
        
        return new JScrollPane(tblLines);
    }

}
```

Comment: I apologize for posting a silly question. I realized I had placed the instructions that set the table column width in the wrong place.  They worked when I moved them to the initialization section.